# Minimum set of pins to block HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I am trying to build a device to block HDMI signal (from receiver perspective, i.e. the TV) and I was wondering if there is a minimum number of pins (ideally one) that I can use to accomplish such a feat with Mosfets in an easy revert-able way. Mosfet Active -> Signal blocked; Mosfet Low -> Signal goes through.
Specifications are not clear.

Comment: Why that way? It would be easier to not shunt a signal but series pass it or preventing it from passing. Disconnecting only one signal should be enough. Pick any.

Answer (score 0):

The HPD (hot plug detect) signal can be forced low at the sink. This will make the source device disconnect.

Comment: Yes, but it might not be a good idea to clamp the HPD output low. Not all devices are within required output impedance specs, unfortunately.

Comment: The sink device has the pull-up, so it’s in control of how much current it can source to the source.

Comment: Assuming there's a pull-up to begin with. If it is an incompliant device, better not assume you can externally pull down HPD output safely. Therefore it's better to not parallel shunt it, just series pass it or not.

Comment: That's what I thought. But I assembled one of these and it didn't work, I am suspecting a MosFET should do the trick (I am learning on the go, I would have thought a transistor would have worked as well; or the board might be defective or I did a mistake)
https://easyeda.com/no1ookpass/hdmi-panic

Comment: The idea was to ground the HPD pin to force the source to think that no sink is connected. You could also use an n-FET, in series with HPD, to disconnect the sink pull-up. I think this is what @justme was getting at, since the sink pull-up could be something other than the 1.5k resistor.

Comment: Try grounding HPD with a voltmeter on the mA setting and see what you get. This should force a disconnect, and you’d see how stiff the pull-up is.

Comment: @Paperino Of course the schematic won't work. First of all, the transistor circuit is an emitter follower, it does not need 5V on collector, the emitter will follow whatever Arduino output is, minus 0.7V. Assuming the Arduino even gets powered up, as 5V needs to provide only 55mA out, and no device is allowed to consume 50mA.